# Encoding Querystring Params

Tags: asp.net

I am wondering if maybe I have this wrong with the double %%

http://www.someone.com/SomePage.aspx?aid=%%MA_ID%%&tid=%%RECI_ID%%&

is it %% or % to encode querystring values?

Answer (score 1):

Though the direct answer to your question is: "URL encoding uses a single %"...

I believe that link is NOT url encoded.
Simply put, neither %MA nor %%MA is a valid URL token - the % is followed by a hexadecimal value, i.e. to characters 0-9A-F.
I'm thinking this is some kind of internal encoding scheme, by the 3rd party processor you mentioned in the comments.

As such, either way might be the right answer for you, or neither, or both :-(.
Sorry this isnt more helpful, but you'll just have to check out the documentation for the 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

Single.........(15 chars...phew)

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually encoding the url parameters? If so, try using [HttpServerUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.aspx)'s UrlEncode() or HtmlEncode() methods.  You can access it from the page with the [Page.Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.server.aspx) property.

Comment: I give this link to a 3rd party email processor and they send back the encoded values for us.  We don't decode anything.  The issue is, one of the params being sent back is changing on us...the very end of it so I was wondering if the %% had anything to do with that.  But when I tried just one % up there for each of those, then I get just text back so that doesn't work either.  I gethttp://www.someone.com/SomePage.aspx?aid=%MA%5FID%&tid=%RECI%5FID% back

Comment: That's a strange way to encode url parameters. Going along with @AviD's answer, %5F could be a valid escaped token, but not %MA or %RE ...